# Build a Map with Custom Animated Markers and Region Focus when Content is Scrolled in NATIVE android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-recyclerview

[image]

I have a list of places to visit with lat and lng coords, so when a person click on one of the location pin in map it should scroll to that card .

Comment: What are you using as a card holder? RecyclerView or Horizontal Scrollview or?

Comment: im using recyclerView

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you data models are the same (data model for markers = data model for recyclerView items) or at least they share the same latitude and longitude.

What you should do on onMarkerClick(Marker marker) is something like this:

```
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
    for (DataModel model : recyclerViewAdapter.getDataModels()){
         LatLng latLng = marker.getPosition();
         // now everything is speculation from this point on
         // You need to check if latLng equals the latLng of the model
         // and then you use recyclerview.scrollToPosition(position) where position is the position in the recyclerViewAdapter
         // and finally don't forget to break the loop

    }
    return true;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks but first i want the scrolling effect to impliment beacuse i don't know how to do it too after that i will impliment click behaviour example: when i scroll the cards the marker of the selected card should rise above other markers

Comment: To be aware of what card you are on you need to implement RecyclerView.OnScrollListener(). Inside of it on onScrolled you need to write your own logic to know which card you are on. After that when you know the card, get it's dataModel's LatLng and use googleMap.animateCamera( CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
 coordinate, 15)) to zoom to it (my suggestion) and then use the same logic to find the selected marker and change it's drawable. You have alot of moving parts in this question, and i suggest for next time to show some code and a detailed explanation of what is that you want to do.